# How to readout a Tensorflow CNN into integers after the softmax layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, softmax

My task is to classify an image pixelwise...so each pixel of the image has a class, and the CNN should be able to read out the label image such that each pixel has the discrete value of the class (0-19).

I have a CNN that seems to be doing a good job reproducing the relative values, so that it is approximating the label image with a range of 0.00001 and 0.00002... However, I am having trouble getting the cross entropy to work beyond just "kind of good", since it is relying on the image label matrix with the discrete values:

```
[[0, 1, 1, 1],[1,1,3,3],.etc]  # A 2x4 pixel example
```

Also, I don't think I can rely on onehot vectors, since I would be looking at a 19*227*227 matrix...but maybe I will try that if there is no solution here.

---

Anyhow, how do I do this integer boxing on the returned values in the softmax?  Must I do the 1hot vector for each pixel in the image, or is it possible to change the softmax distribution to the integer classes some other way?

Answer (score 2):

I realize this answer is a bit late but hopefully it'll be helpful. You do not have to create one-hot vectors; you can use `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`.

`labels: Each entry labels[i] must be an index in [0, num_classes) or -1. If -1, the corresponding loss will be 0, regardless of the contents of logits[i].`

See the link below for its documentation and the link below that for an example of it used in a tutorial CIFAR-10 network.
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/nn.html#sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10.py

Hope this helps!